# Как подключить PhpStorm к удаленному отладчику

Tags: php, phpstorm, ssh, xdebug, jetbrains

У меня есть проект, развернутый на удаленном сервере, над которым я работаю в PhpStorm через ssh.

Собственно, вопрос: можно ли к PhpStorm как-нибудь через ssh подключить xdebug или какой-нибудь другой отладчик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, я так и веду отладку кода.

На сервере ставите xdebug (пример для CentOS 7 и php 7.1):

```
yum -y install php71w-pecl-xdebug
```

Статья про настройки xdebug [здесь](https://jonathansblog.co.uk/install-xdebug-in-centos7-with-php7).

Мои настройки /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="my.ip.xx.xx"
xdebug.remote_port=9002
xdebug.idekey="some_password"

#xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
#xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
#xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
```

Статья о настройках PhpStorm [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html).

Подробнее ответить сложно, не понимая, какая у вас ОС на удалённом сервере и что на локальной машине.

Comment: Сделал также, только еще пробросил порты через ssh. Не знал что через ssh можно прбрасывать порты)